# Difference between using jQuery and angular element reference in angular directive

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I want to wrap some jQuery in angular. So I do this in the link function

```
 $('#slider').slider();
```

But I am wondering what the difference is to....

```
 $(elem).slider();
```

Because the second one only 'sort of' works.

Comment: What's `elem`? An HTMLElement object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'elem' variable in your link function is 'made' by angular using jqLite.

From the docs:

> jqLite is a tiny, API-compatible subset of jQuery that allows Angular
>   to manipulate the DOM in a cross-browser compatible way. jqLite
>   implements only the most commonly needed functionality with the goal
>   of having a very small footprint.

Answer (score 0):

This is what is available to an angular element.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element

I don't advise trying to type an angular element directly to a jquery element.  If you really need to do that pull the class and id property off of the angular element and create the jquery one manually.

Comment: Or... just include jquery as angular uses jqlite but replaces it with jquery if it has it. 'To use `jQuery`, simply ensure it is loaded before the `angular.js` file.'

Answer (score 0):

In angularjs directives you dont need to use `$(elem).slider();` this is jQuery.

To call the element you just need to type `elem.somejqLiteFunc()`

Example

```
.directive('someDirective', function () {
      return {
          restrict: 'E',
          link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
              element.on('click', function () {
                  element.html('You clicked me!');
              });
          }
      };
  });
```

You can see all default jqLite functions in Angular Docs site: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element